# Concatenate a static dataframe with Structured streaming dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, static-data

How could I union or concatenate a static dataframe with only one row to a stream dataframe with around 500 rows in spark. it is somehow put a stamp or mark (add a row to each table) for each streaming dataframe.
Adding more, my streaming data has no timestamp and I'm wondering if I can use foreach() or foreachBatch() or not?
I really appreciate it if you can help me.